# Powershell script to install multiple applications using an array and scriptblock

Tags: arrays, powershell

Need help troubleshooting an the Array and Scriptblock
OR Maybe this is better using param and functions???

Script Objective: To easily update the list of applications to be installed

Getting error below.

'
At C:\Temp\appinstall.ps1:7 char:10
$Firefox={
~
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept
assignments, such as a variable or a property.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide
'

```
Start-Transcript -Append c:\Deploy\log.txt
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';
#Change App Name, Source, MSI/EXE, Argument

$AppArray= (

$Firefox={
$App= "Firefox";
$App_source= "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win64&lang=en-US";
$destination = "c:\Deploy\$App.exe";
$Argument= "/S";
},

$Chrome=
{
$App= "Chrome";
$App_source= "https://dl.google.com/tag/s/defaultbrowser/edgedl/chrome/install/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi";
$destination = "c:\Deploy\$App.exe";
$Argument= "/norestart","/qn";
}
)


$InstallScriptBlock=
{
$installed = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where { $_.DisplayName -Match "$App" });
$installed.displayname
if ($installed.displayname -Match $App) {
    Write-Host "$software installed"
}else{
If ((Test-Path $destination) -eq $false) {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $destination -Force
}
#install software
Invoke-WebRequest $App_source -OutFile $destination
Start-Process -FilePath "$destination" -ArgumentList "$Argument" -Wait
#Delete installer
Remove-Item -recurse "$destination"
}
}

ForEach ($Program in $AppArray) {Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $InstallScriptBlock}

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: I would recommend creating a parameterized function for this kind of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a nested [*hashtable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`), but your syntax is flawed - see the linked docs.

However:

- It should suffice in your case to create an *array* of hashtables to iterate over with `foreach`
- There's no need to use a separate [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) - just use the body of the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) loop statement.

  - As an aside: While using [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) for local invocation of script blocks works, it usually isn't necessary, because `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), will do (e.g. `$sb = { 'hi' }; & $sb`). `Invoke-Command`'s primary purpose is to execute a script block *on a remote machine*.
- Generally, you can use variables as-is as command arguments, without enclosing them in `"..."` - even if their values contain spaces. E.g., `Write-Output $foo` is sufficient, no need for `Write-Output "$foo"`

To put it all together:

```
# Create an array whose elements are hashtables.
$appArray = (
  @{
    App         = ($thisApp = 'Firefox')
    App_source  = 'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win64&lang=en-US'
    Destination = "c:\Deploy\$thisApp.exe"
    Argument    = '/S'
  },
  @{
    App         = ($thisApp = 'Chrome')
    App_source  = 'https://dl.google.com/tag/s/defaultbrowser/edgedl/chrome/install/GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi'
    Destination = "c:\Deploy\$thisApp.exe"
    Argument    = '/norestart /qn'
  }
)

foreach ($app in $appArray) {
  # Note how $app.<key> is used to refer to the entries of the hashtable at hand,
  # e.g. $app.App yields "Firefox" for the first hashtable.
  $installed = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -Match $app.App }
  $installed.displayname
  if ($installed.displayname -Match $app.App) {
    Write-Host "$($app.App) already installed."
  }
  else {
    if ((Test-Path $app.Destination) -eq $false) {
      New-Item -ItemType File -Path $app.Destination -Force
    }
    #install software
    Invoke-WebRequest $app.App_source -OutFile $app.Destination
    Start-Process -FilePath $app.Destination -ArgumentList $app.Argument -Wait
    #Delete installer
    Remove-Item -Recurse $app.Destination
  }
}
```

Note:

- I've removed unnecessary `;` and I've switched to using [verbatim (single-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) (`'...'`) when no string interpolation via [expandable (double-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (`"..."`) is required, both for conceptual clarity and to avoid potentially unwanted expansions.
- Note the use of aux. variable `$thisApp` in the `App` key, which allows referencing it in the later `Destination` key, in an expandable string (`"c:\Deploy\$thisApp.exe"`).

  - [GitHub suggestion #13782](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13782) looks for a more elegant way to allow hashtable entries to reference one another.